# How could you compare two time series regarding their environmental properties?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python

Along a path leading through buildings and out, environmental properties are measured, such as temperature, barometric pressure/humidity, light, magnetic field, etc. Especially the light spectrum values ​​seem a bit random so I'm not sure how compare two multivariate time series regarding their environmental properties.

The data was recorded throughout the year, which is why outdoor values ​​such as temperature, humidity or light can vary in the same places.

Basically, I have to check whether my methods for generating synthetic training data like scaling the data points, adding noises to it etc. produce realistic data.

Do you have any suggestions for comparing environmental variables of time series which can vary dependent on when the data were recorded e.g. the temperature: 0 degrees in december and 30 degrees in july on the same spot outside. At the end I have to tell whether the synthetically generated time series regarding aforementioned environmental properties is realistic given recorded time series

Comment: Isn't "time series which can vary dependent on when the data were recorded" tautological?  That describes all time series.  Could you clarify what you mean by this, as well as by "metrics to compare"?  Your question is currently too vague to be answerable in our format.

Comment: I mean because of the temperature for example. It may be that in december it is colder than in may or july on the same spot outside

Comment: Well, of course!  But that doesn't help us understand your question, which hinges on knowing what are your "methods for generating synthetic training data" and having some characterization of "realistic" data.  We need information about these things if we're to provide useful, objective answers.